# JQuery check for Tab key and clicks to next control

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need fire a AJax call to check for a field validation when the user presses "Tab" and voluntarily moves the tab to next control. The below code works fine for the "tab" but I would like to know how to check if the user has voluntarily clicked the next control using a mouse. Initially, I used "blur" but that gets fired even if the user moves to a different window.

Thanks in advance..

Here is existing JQuery code-

```
$("#table_appl,#table_enfr,#table_det01,#table_det02,#table_det03,#table_det04,#table_det05,#table_datais").on( "keydown", "input:text", function( event ) {

    if (event.keyCode === 9){
```

Comment: Just a side note...why don't you give those elements a single class that you can just select all of them by instead of selecting each id?

Comment: Thanks for your comments...it makes more sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could add onfocus to those fields, so if that input is focused by "tab" or clicking, this event will be fired.

```
$("#table_appl,#table_enfr,#table_det01,#table_det02,#table_det03,#table_det04,#table_det05,#table_datais").on( "focus", "input:text", function( event ) {})
```

Answer (score 0):

Onblur=”validate()”

Or set a jqueru blur event?